# recursive tag match using regular expression PHP

Tags: php, regex, recursion, tags

I'm using "special" tags, but I have a problem with recursivity. There's an example:

```
<!-- BEGIN foo --> parent text <!-- BEGIN bar --> child text <!-- END --> aditional parent text<!-- END --> <!-- BEGIN foobar --> third text <!-- END -->
```

When I used `[^BEGIN]` it worked great until I haven't typed B inside tags. The same it is with `[^<!\-\-]`. I was playing around with `(?!BEGIN)` and `(?<!BEGIN)` with no success.

My last try looks like this (but it is not working):

```
#<!--\s?BEGIN\s?(.+?)\s?-->((?!BEGIN).|(?R))*<!--\s?END\s?-->#s
```

Thanks for your answers,
Tom

Comment: Rregular Expression are only suited for stateless grammars. You should use a parser.

Comment: that is more or less html, as far as syntax and structure is concerned. regex is a painful way to parse html, if you want it parsed properly. Maybe you could change to a more xml like open/close tag, and then just use an xml or html parser. You could probably preg_replace your way to that format.

Comment: What type of parser do you mean?

Comment: @user1440445 have you considered DOMDocument for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#<!-- BEGIN [a-z]+ -->([a-z ]*(?R)?[a-z ]*)<!-- END -->#
```

Actually, don't try that; as mentioned in the comments, parsers should really be preferred for recursive parsing. But [this *does* work](http://ideone.com/E9Uzy).

Just note that:

- I made a few assumptions about your input (like assuming 'foo' and 'bar' will always be alphanumeric and that the spaces are non-optional.) You can change these back easily enough.
- It will only capture the bottom-most layer of matching tags. Once you have those, you'll need to run it again if you wish to find any nested matches. The recursivity is only used for matching the begin with its appropriate end.

Comment: What type of parser do you mean. Anyway your example works until I write basic HTML comment (<!-- comment -->) inside tags.

Comment: @user1440445 A parser that can parse the language you've contrived. Something with a state, not a regular expression.

Comment: @user1440445 `<!-- comment -->` breaks the expression because `<!-- comment -->` was not specified in your question. You can change the possible body characters (`[a-z ]`) to better fit your own needs.

Comment: Well the problem is that I am building the parser and this won't work, because it has to accept HTML, that's why it should accept any string except <!-- BEGIN something -->. I hope you understand me.